# Give preference to JS file function over HTML file

Tags: javascript

I have two functions of the same name; let's say `foo()`.

One in the HTML file and one in the JS file, which is included in the HTML file. The problem is I want to give preference to the JS file function rather than the HTML file function.

Is there any way to do that, or is there any syntax in JavaScript like `[JSFileName].foo()`, that may perhaps call the function in the JS file?

Comment: Try to insert the javascript file before the script code in your html file.

Comment: *Why* is there a naming collision here? Do you not control either the script or the page? (I'm not being purely rhetorical -- that information will affect the nature of the answer.)

Comment: @Antoine you mean insert the file after the script code

Comment: He said he wants to give preferency to the js file. So, the js file has to be included BEFORE script code.

Comment: @Antoine, exactly, you have it backwards.  Preference is given to the last one listed, not the first.

Comment: @Antoine What ever code comes last wins

Comment: @apsillers actually the function one is in a ASP.NET control and the other is in a JS file (not originally meant to be used in html file in which it is used now)

Comment: Yeah right, but I haven't seen the problem that way actually. I thought it was about how executing the code in the js file first, no matter what comes after

Comment: @Antoine, yes thats what I want to ask, you gave the correct words :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you want to have two identically-named functions.

The snarky answer is:  Just remove the reference to the function you don't want. (If you have control over your html, such a situation shouldn't exist.)

The answer you're looking for: **Place the external script tag after the inline script tag.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script tag for the js file is after the HTML script tag in which `foo` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question why you have two functions named `foo`, but based on your `[JSFileName].foo()` attempt at a solution, I might suggest using objects as namespaces. In your script you could do:

```
var myScriptFunctions = {
    foo: function() {
        // do foo stuff
    }
}
```

You can call it with `myScriptFunctions.foo()` and you won't have two functions competing for the global name `foo`.